# The import org.hibernate.validator.Length cannot be resolved?

Tags: java, hibernate, maven

Here is my pom:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts2-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.16</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.9</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts2-fullhibernatecore-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2-GA</version>
        </dependency>

         <!-- validation -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- for annotations like @Entity,@Table -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.0.GA</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- dependencies of hibernate-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

How to resolve this error :

```
The import org.hibernate.validator.Length cannot be resolved
```

Edit :

```
[ERROR]   symbol:   class Length
  location: class User
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be missing the `constraints` [package name](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.1/api/org/hibernate/validator/constraints/Length.html) in your code

```
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.Length;
```

Comment: Yes. For previous versions of hibernate-annotations.jar it was ok but after I changed the version to 3.4.0.GA the path has changed.

Comment: Please, tell me also where `@Valid` annotation was shifted from `org.hibernate.validator` package.

Comment: You mean `javax.validation.Valid`. It's part of the `validation-api` which you have already :)

Comment: Not I mean `org.hibernate.validator.Valid`. It is used to tell struts that this object has hibernate constraints.

Comment: I tries `javax.validation.Valid` and it doesn't work.

Comment: Comparing the 2 annotations they appear identical and very simple - it would seem like that that one (from JSR 303) is intended to replace the old hibernate version. Probably best to post a new question to include these new (& different) errors

Comment: I posted this question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21532136/how-to-trigger-validation-with-valid-annotation-in-struts2)

Answer (score 3):

Since you have the `hibernate-validator` dependency set, you will have to run

```
mvn clean install
```

in order to get it added to the classpath.

Comment: When I run it shows compilation errors that my imports are not resolved. See edit.

Comment: Did you run `mvn clean install` ?

Comment: Yes I did. And this caused the error. I ran that on pom.xml I provided in my question.

Comment: In eclipse I search for this annotation with Ctrl+T and it doesn't find it. Maybe it's needed to add another jar

Comment: You can open `Project Properties -> Deployment Assembly` and then add the Maven Libraries. Then try again to import it.