# How to trigger validation with @Valid annotation in struts2?

Tags: java, hibernate, struts2, bean-validation, struts2-jsr303-plugin

I cannot make `@javax.validation.Valid` annotation work in hibernate,struts2 webapp.

Here is my simple Entity with constraints:

```
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.Length;
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty;

    @Entity
    @Table(name = "user")
    public class User implements Serializable {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue
        @Column(name = "user_id")
        private Long id;
        @NotEmpty
        @Length(max = 50, min = 3, message = "Name should be not less 3 and not more 50")
        @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
        private String name;
        @Length(min = 6, max = 10)
        @Column(name = "password")
        private String password;
        @NotEmpty(message = "Please select a gender")
        @Column(name = "gender")
        private String gender;
        @NotEmpty(message = "Please select a country")
        @Column(name = "country")
        private String country;
        @Length(max = 100)
        @Column(name = "aboutYou")
        private String aboutYou;
        @Column(name = "mailinglist")
        private Boolean mailingList;
```

Here is my UserAction class that uses `@Valid` annotation:

```
public class UserAction extends ActionSupport implements ModelDriven<User> {

    @Valid
    private User user = new User();
    private UserDao dao = new UserDao();
    private List<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();

    public String addUser() {
        dao.addUser(user);
        users = dao.listUsers();
        return SUCCESS;
    }

    public List<User> getUsers() {
        return users;
    }

    public User getModel() {
        return user;
    }
}
```

Here is my jsp which should display error messages when hibernate constraints fail.

```xml
<h4>Add user:</h4>
    <s:actionerror/>
    <s:form action="addUser">
        <s:textfield key="name" />
        <s:password key="password" />
        <s:radio list="{'Male','Female'}" key="gender" />
        <s:select list="{'India','USA','Ukraine'}" headerKey=""
            headerValue="Select" key="country" />
        <s:textarea key="aboutYou" cols="20" rows="10" />
        <s:checkbox key="mailingList" value="true" />
        <s:submit value="Post" />
    </s:form>
```

When I submit empty form then **no hibernate constraint works** and new user is added to database and of course no error is displayed on jsp page.

Don't you know what's wrong?

**EDIT**. After trying to use recommended plugin I got NullPointer because hibernate Session wasn't injected with help of @SesionTarget annotation.
Here is my struts.xml that extends jsr303 instead of hibernate-default.

```xml
<package name="default" extends="jsr303">
        <default-interceptor-ref name="jsr303ValidationStack"/>

        <action name="index" class="com.shb.action.UserAction" method="execute">
            <result name="success">/index.jsp</result>
            <result name="input">/index.jsp</result>
        </action>

        <action name="addUser" class="com.shb.action.UserAction" method="addUser">
            <result name="success">/index.jsp</result>
            <result name="input">/index.jsp</result>
        </action>
    </package>
```

Comment: Do you have already tried the pretty new struts2-jsr303 plugin? https://github.com/umeshawasthi/jsr303-validator-plugin

Comment: @jogep, can you see my EDIT?

Comment: @jogep. This plugin works if I not use struts2-fullhibernatecore-plugin. But when I use it then validating errors are not shown on my jsp page, but it still prevents hibernate to insert new user.

Comment: @VolodymyrLevytskyi: Can you have any sample application showing issue you have mentioned? I am wondering what is stopping plugin not to show errors on UI..Can you put some sample app on github or anywhere else if possible.